# Cookies doesn't create themselves

Tags: php, cookies

I've been looking for 1 hour, and yet I'm not that new to it, but I DON'T UNDERSTAND what I'm doing wrong.

I have a code to create cookies:

```
setcookie("id", $_POST['username'], time()+365*24*3600, "", "www.mysite.com");
```

And nothing helps, a var dump of $ _COOKIE ['id'] constantly returns me a NULL.

What's going on ?

Comment: I believe, you place call to the `setcookie` prior to any output, including `<html>` and `<head>` tags as well as any whitespace? According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Have you tried with the `php 7.3` alternative : `setcookie("id", $_POST['username'], ['expires'=>time()+365*24*3600, 'path'=>"", 'domain' => "www.mysite.com"]);
`

Comment: Can you show us how and where you call the `setcookie` function from within your page/code?

Answer (score 1):

The [setcookie documentation at php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) says if buffering is not enabled setcookie() should be called before any other content is sent to browser. Because setcookie() sets HTTP header. Without buffering, the first content written to browser will cause all headers to be sent, and following set header calls will not do anything.

Another thing from same link:

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was
> successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before
> the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expires parameter. A
> nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling
> `print_r($_COOKIE);`.

Comment: Well, I have just a few verifications before the set cookies :

Comment: Try also setting the path parameter to "/" instead of "", and make sure the domain parameter value is same as what the browser is using to access the page. In doubt you can try not setting those at all to see that will make difference.

Answer (score 0):

I can't set it before anything else, I've got a few verifications first

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=host.hosting-data.io;dbname=dtb','username','password');
$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username'");
$req->execute();
$user = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if ($req->rowcount() == 0)
{
    $_SESSION['login_error'] = 1;
    header("Location:../account.php");
}
elseif ($_POST['password'] != $user->password)
{
    $_SESSION['login_error'] = 2;
    header("Location:../account.php");
}
elseif ($_POST['password'] == $user->password)
{
    $_SESSION['id'] = $user->username;
    
        setcookie("id", $_POST['username'], ['expires'=>time()+365*24*3600, 'path'=>"", 'domain' => "www.site.com"]);
        
    
    header("Location:../account.php");
}

} // Fin submit
?>
```